Unity cloud build failed: Could not get resource ‘https://aa-sdk.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/android_repo/
when i try to build on unity cloud build, sometime i got this error. Seem like there is something wrong with the internet of the cloud machine? When i build on my local pc this error never happend.

[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] * What went wrong:
[error] [2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] Execution failed for task ‘:launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses’.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not resolve all files for configuration ‘:launcher:releaseRuntimeClasspath’.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-gamingservices:[17.0.0,18).
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] Required by:
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] project :launcher > project :unityLibrary
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-gamingservices.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://developer.huawei.com/repo/com/facebook/android/facebook-gamingservices/maven-metadata.xml.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not get resource ‘https://developer.huawei.com/repo/com/facebook/android/facebook-gamingservices/maven-metadata.xml’.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not GET ‘https://developer.huawei.com/repo/com/facebook/android/facebook-gamingservices/maven-metadata.xml’.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Read timed out
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not resolve com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.7.3.300.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] Required by:
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] project :launcher > project :unityLibrary
[error] [2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Skipped due to earlier error
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not resolve com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.7.3.300.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not get resource ‘https://aa-sdk.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/android_repo/com/huawei/agconnect/agconnect-core/1.7.3.300/agconnect-core-1.7.3.300.pom’.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not GET ‘https://aa-sdk.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/android_repo/com/huawei/agconnect/agconnect-core/1.7.3.300/agconnect-core-1.7.3.300.pom’. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not resolve com.huawei.hms:ads-identifier:3.4.58.301.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] Required by:
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] project :launcher > project :unityLibrary
[error] [2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Skipped due to earlier error
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not resolve com.huawei.hms:ads-identifier:3.4.58.301.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not get resource ‘https://aa-sdk.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/android_repo/com/huawei/hms/ads-identifier/3.4.58.301/ads-identifier-3.4.58.301.pom’.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not GET ‘https://aa-sdk.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/android_repo/com/huawei/hms/ads-identifier/3.4.58.301/ads-identifier-3.4.58.301.pom’. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not resolve com.huawei.hms:opendevice:6.7.0.300.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] Required by:
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] project :launcher > project :unityLibrary
[error] [2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Skipped due to earlier error
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not resolve com.huawei.hms:opendevice:6.7.0.300.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not get resource ‘https://aa-sdk.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/android_repo/com/huawei/hms/opendevice/6.7.0.300/opendevice-6.7.0.300.pom’.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] > Could not GET ‘https://aa-sdk.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/android_repo/com/huawei/hms/opendevice/6.7.0.300/opendevice-6.7.0.300.pom’. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity]
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] * Try:
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[2024-09-10T03:36:30Z - Unity] 

sometime it work just by trying to build again, sometime not.
